# Get all selected optgroups in bootstrap multiselect

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using this multiselect plugin (https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)
I have set selectable optgroups on.

It is clear how to get selected options under optgroups.

selected Options gives your all selected options, but it does not contain selected optgoups

How to get selected optgoups in array.
Thanks in advnace for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the `optgroup` elements that contain a `:checked` option.

Example:

```js
const select = $('select');
select.multiselect({
  enableClickableOptGroups: true,
  onChange(el) {
    const groups = select.find('optgroup:has(option:checked)').map((_, el) => el.label).get();
    console.log(groups);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/1.1.2/css/bootstrap-multiselect.min.css" integrity="sha512-fZNmykQ6RlCyzGl9he+ScLrlU0LWeaR6MO/Kq9lelfXOw54O63gizFMSD5fVgZvU1YfDIc6mxom5n60qJ1nCrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.4/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/1.1.2/js/bootstrap-multiselect.min.js" integrity="sha512-lxQ4VnKKW7foGFV6L9zlSe+6QppP9B2t+tMMaV4s4iqAv4iHIyXED7O+fke1VeLNaRdoVkVt8Hw/jmZ+XocsXQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<select multiple>
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <option value="1-1">Option 1.1</option>
        <option value="1-2">Option 1.2</option>
        <option value="1-3">Option 1.3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <option value="2-1">Option 2.1</option>
        <option value="2-2">Option 2.2</option>
        <option value="2-3">Option 2.3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: My optgroup is selectable, so it has its own checkbox.
it has enableClickableOptGroups: true, and that option adds checkbox in optgroups
I want to know if that checkbox is selected or not.
In your example I do not see checkbox near optgroup label.
btw, I have hidden all checkboxes from options. I do not need options selected.

Comment: @Felichino Can you post the code you have so far? That will make it easier to be on the same page.

Comment: $('.dropdownFilter').multiselect({
            enableClickableOptGroups: true,
            enableCollapsibleOptGroups: true,
            collapseOptGroupsByDefault: true,
            enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
            maxHeight: 500,
            dropDown: true
        });

  <select class="dropdownFilter" id="dropdownFilter" style="width:390px;" multiple="multiple">
here a I have rasor code for select options and optgroups
</select>

Comment: @Felichino I've updated the example to use `enableClickableOptGroups`.

Comment: yes, your code works, but it is showing me empty array, cause I am using older version of multiselect. changing it to new version gives me a lot off UI errors(